# Error evited pod on with apim run on kubernetes

Tags: wso2, apim

I install wso2 api-manager with pattern-3 run on Kubernetes, however, the pod is evicted after pods start successfully in a short time (30 minutes).
I edited the limit memory to 1GB, 2GB, 3GB, but the issue is not solved. How do i fixed it

[pod is evicted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebGOQ.png)

[reason error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRK5v.png)

My resources server:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pSqE.png)

Comment: You can have the same values for request and limit values in the resources section.

Comment: Thank @Pubci the issue has been fixed:
first: I change request and limit values to different values.
second: I calculate limit resource less than resource on the node.
third: I delete selector node in file deployment.yaml